# Can't Access Gui or cli interface on Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I tried to uninstall MariaDB and Apache2 but it just flashes saying falled to Start MariaDB 10.6.16 database server

Comment: You're doing *what*?